# z-index não funciona em link

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Estou tendo um problema ao criar uma `<div>` de mascara e um link para desabilitar essa mascara. Em outro layout que eu tinha funcionava normalmente, agora que estou efetuando a troca ele parou de funcionar. Tenho o seguinte código:

```
<div class="mascara" style="display: <?php echo ($this->conta_model->user('luz') == '0') ? 'block' : 'none';?>"></div>

<div class="user-controls">
<ul>

<li><a href="javascript:void(0);" id="botao" data-ref="<?php echo $this->conta_model->user('luz');?>"><img src="<?php echo base_url('uploads/shop/'.$luz.'.png');?>" id="imgluz" style="margin-top:-13px;" width="21"></a></li>

</ul>
</div>
```

Explicando esse código, ele da `block` ou `none` no `display` da **.mascara** dependendo da informação que está no banco. O Link **#botao** ele altera essa informação no banco, assim mudando via `jQuery` a **.mascara** para `none` ou `block` também, mas para isso acontecer o link tem que ser clicavel e por causa da mascará que tem a `z-index: 1050` ele não deixa. Já tentei colocar o `z-index` do link como `9999` mas não resolveu. O Link é o único que tem que estar em cima da **.mascara** sobre qualquer circunstância.

CSS **.mascara**

```
.mascara{
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: #000;
    width: 100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    opacity:.80;
    filter: alpha(opacity=80);
    -moz-opacity: 0.80;
    z-index: 1050;
}
```

Comment: O `z-index` só funciona em elementos posicionados, experimente colocar `position: relative` no link

Comment: Já tentei colocar a position como `relative`, `absolute` e `fixed` mas nada resolveu ;/

Comment: @AlissonAcioli Ele esta utilizado bootstrap? coloca codigo para ver a simular por houve de erro, adicione code snippet, possamos acompanhar.

Comment: ja tentou um z-index alto e com important? `z-index: 9999 !important;`. Como ja foi falado precisa do `position` `relative`ou `absolute`.

Comment: Estava utilizando .link { width: 100%; height: 98px; display: block; z-index: 99999; } E o `z-index` não funcionava, coloquei o `position: relative` e funcionou perfeitamente, tks

Answer (score 2):

da um `float`, pois ele precisa estar solto dos outros elementos pro `z-index` funcionar, caso persista, coloca uma classe na `li` com o `float`, `position` e ai sim a `z-index` :D

Answer (score 2):

Como pode ser visto em https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-PT/docs/Web/CSS/z-index a propriedade z-index se aplica somente em elemento posicionados. Sendo assim, adicionando `position: relative;` ao elemento `#botao` deveria fazer com que a propriedade funcionasse normalmente, como no [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4e7200j2/).

```css
.mascara{
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: #000;
    width: 100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    opacity:.80;
    filter: alpha(opacity=80);
    -moz-opacity: 0.80;
    z-index: 1050;
}

#botao {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1055;
}
```

```html
<div class="mascara" style="display: block;"></div>
<div class="user-controls">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#" id="botao" data-ref=""><img src="#" id="imgluz"></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Dependendo da sua aplicação, outra solução seria mover o `.user-controls` para dentro do `div.mascara` como [aqui](https://jsfiddle.net/xyq5fqft/1/).

```css
.mascara{
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: #000;
    width: 100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    opacity:.80;
    filter: alpha(opacity=80);
    -moz-opacity: 0.80;
    z-index: 1050;
}
```

```html
<div class="mascara" style="display: block;">
  <div class="user-controls">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" id="botao" data-ref=""><img src="#" id="imgluz"></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```