# Como deixo div sobreposta a outra div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Como deixo a `div #inner-block` em primeiro plano?

```css
#block-1
{
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  background-color: #999;
  z-index: 1;
}
#inner-block
{
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 20px;
  background-color: #777;
  z-index: 100;
}
#block-2
{
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  top: 60px;
  left: 60px;
  background-color: #666;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div id="block-1"><div id="inner-block"></div></div>
<div id="block-2"></div>
```

Comment: Coloque `#block-1` com z-index maior que o `#block-2`, ou seja, de 3 ou mais.

Comment: z-index so funciona com elementos com position absolute ou fixed

Comment: Parece-me que a estrutura html utilizada não é a ideal para o efeito que pretende obter. Porque motivo a `div` `block-2` ficaria a meio das outras duas, apesar de ser um elemento que não se relaciona com elas no html ? Parece ser um problema estrutural

Comment: Concordo com o @Isac , Como vc quer que o filho de um elemento se sobreponha a um elemento que é irmão do pai. Isso não é possível... No seu caso acredito que vc deveria colocar a div id="inner-block" dentro de div id="block-2". Veja que a hierarquia do z-index do filho  id="inner-block" é referente ao próprio pai, e não ao irmão do pai!

Comment: Sam preciso que o #block-3 fique na frente do block-1 e antes do block-2

Comment: O block-2 e hide e ta ficando abaixo do block-3. E se vc colocar block-1 primeiro que o block-3. O block-3 quando fica em sticky fica abaixo do block-1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apesar de e estrutura html não ser a ideal. Ainda é possivel chegar ao resultado esperado! Mas primeiro temos que entender porque não funciona... **Vamos la!**

Primeiro temos que entender que o [z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-PT/docs/Web/CSS/z-index):

- [Só funciona em elementos posicionados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/146748/z-index-n%C3%A3o-funciona-em-link)

*E o mais importante para enteder porque não funciona no seu caso*

- **Não é herdado**

Isso significa que quando você atribuiu o z-index ao 1 ao elemento **#block-1** ele faz com que seus filhos não recebam o mesmo.

Para funcionar usando `z-index` bastaria remove-lo do elemento **#block-1**

```css
#block-1
{
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  background-color: #999;
}
#inner-block
{
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 20px;
  background-color: #777;
  z-index: 100;
}
#block-2
{
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  top: 60px;
  left: 60px;
  background-color: #666;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div id="block-1"><div id="inner-block"></div></div>
<div id="block-2"></div>
```